# How do I send data from a WYSIWYG to a database (Vue.js)

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, vuejs2, wysiwyg

I just started using the Vue2Editor with the intention to replace the many forms that I use to send text and image data to my Firebase database.
My problem is that I cannot get it to add the data entered in the editor.

When using forms, I would just attach an event handler to the form itself and make a function that allowed the transfer.

Example:

```
<form @submit.prevent="addText">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" v-model="fname">
</form>
<button type="submit" variant="success">Save</button>
```

But when using the Vue2Editor, I do not get any form tags.
I just get a "vue-editor" tag. I tried adding the event handler inside this tag, but nothing happens.
I don't get any errors, but the data is not transferred to the database upon submitting it.

This is the code:

```
<template>

<div class="container">

  <div class="text_editor">

  <h2>Add new content</h2>

  <vue-editor @submit.prevent="addText" v-model="textblock" />

  <button type="submit" class="textblock_btn" variant="success">Save</button>

  </div>

</div>

</template>


<script>

import db from '@/firebase/init'

import Vue from "vue";

import Vue2Editor from "vue2-editor";

Vue.use(Vue2Editor);

export default {

  name: 'textblock',

  data () {

    return {

      textblock: null

    }

  },

      methods: {

        addText(){

            db.collection('textblock').add({

                textblock: this.textblock

            }).then(() => {

                this.$router.push({ name: 'Index' })

            }).catch(err => {

                console.log(err)

            })

        }

    }

}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can still wrap the component in a form as the WYSIWYG editor's data is bound to the `v-model` property.

```
<form @submit.prevent="addText">
    <div class="text_editor">

        <h2>Add new content</h2>

        <vue-editor v-model="textblock" />

        <button type="submit" class="textblock_btn" variant="success">Save</button>

    </div>
</form>
```

Within the `addText` method you now have `this.textblock` with the appropriate data on form submission.